# Apache restart after updating php pages

Tags: apache2, php

I have to restart apache every time i update a php file. It's not a client browser cache problem, I tried multiple browsers. The strange thing is I only need to do it with php files, html files updates fine..

Comment: What happens if you don't restart apache? Have you tried to purge apache and install it again? Is apache up to date?

Comment: How do your run PHP? Do you use CGI, PHP-FPM or mod_php?

Comment: If i don't restart apache the page won't update. Tried to purge apache, and is the latest version from the 13.10 repositories. I run php with mod_php

Comment: I assume you also tried Shift+F5 (or your browser's equivalent) to refresh the browser's cache and have it re-request the page right?

Comment: @user3320468 do you use Varnish or APC (Alternative PHP Cache)? Post the output of `apachectl -l`.

Comment: I have also tried Shift+F5 and multiple browsers. Don't use Varnish or APC. apachectl -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  mod_watchdog.c
  http_core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  mod_version.c
  mod_unixd.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last... The trouble was caused by OPcache, I just deleted the config ini and now its working :)

Comment: In 13.10, there is no need to delete the config to disable a PHP module. You can use `sudo php5dismod opcache`